# How to choose the return type of an async delegate

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, valuetask

I am passing an async delegate to the LINQ `Select` method, and I would prefer to get a list of [`ValueTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1)s instead of a list of [`Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1)s. How can I do it? Example:

```
var result = (new[] { 0 }).Select(async x => await Task.Yield()).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Result type: {result.GetType()}");
```

> Result type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task[]

This is not desirable. I figured out that I can create the list I want by replacing the async delegate with an async method, like this:

```
var result = (new[] { 0 }).Select(DoAsync).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine($"Result type: {result.GetType()}");
async ValueTask DoAsync(int arg)
{
    await Task.Yield();
}
```

> Result type: System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask[]

This works but it's awkward. Is there any way to keep the neat delegate syntax, and still get the `ValueTask`s I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can explicitly write value task like this

```
var result = (new[] { 0 }).Select<int, ValueTask>(async x => await Task.Yield()).ToArray();
```